# C++ Private mutex access

Tags: c++, multithreading, class, private

In book "C++ Concurrency in Action: Practical Multithreading" by Anthony Williams I found this code example

```
template<typename T>
class threadsafe_stack
{
private:
    std::stack<T> data;
    mutable std::mutex m;
public:
    threadsafe_stack(){}
    threadsafe_stack (const threadsafe_stack& other)
    {
        std::lock_guard<<std::mutex> lock(other.m);

    ... rest of the code.
```

(in my version of the book this is listing 3.5)

Why I have direct access to other object private data (mutex m in this case)?
Maybe I missed something or maybe this is a typo (I have Russian version of the book and there is no errata)

Thanks in advance.

Dmitry.

Comment: Nothing special, you can access `private` members from other instances within the same class.

Comment: What @πάνταῥεῖ said.  Instances can access private data in other instances of the same _class_.  If you think about it - this is the only way copy constructors could be made to work (not to mention `operator=`, etc etc).

Answer (score 1):

This is perfectly normal, the `private` declaration only pertains to child classes and uses of this class, not to other instances of the same class. In fact this is how things like `operator=` work.

eg.

```
class A {
    private:
        int b;
    public:
         A() : b(rand()) {}
         A& operator=(const A& rhs) {
             b = rhs.b;
         }
};

class B : public A {
    public:
       void set(int newB) {
          b = newB; // Not ok.
       }
};

int main() {
    A a, aa;
    a.b = 5; // Not ok.

    a = aa; // Ok.
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot. looks like this aspect completly fllew out of my head.

Comment: @Dimitry, no problem, also http://hyperboleandahalf.blogspot.com/2010/04/alot-is-better-than-you-at-everything.html